# How can I change the format of reference list numbers using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

In biblatex, I would like to have S1, S2, S3,... in the reference list instead of 1, 2, 3,... as in the example below:

As stated in [S1], the pattern provided by device A can resemble the pattern of the device described in [S2].

References

[S1] Smith, A. Theory of useless devices. Journal of Mickey Mouse 9, 12-15 (2014)

[S2] Espino, P. Story of ignominia. Journal of Donald Duck (2014)

Comment: You could use `prefixnumbers=S` in the argument to `\printbibliography`, see p. 75 of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `prefixnumbers={S}` when printing your biblioraphy.

Here's an example

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Author1-2000,
  author = {Author1},
  title = {A title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {2000},
}
@article{Author2-2000,
  author = {Author2},
  title = {A title},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {1999},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[prefixnumbers={S}]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]